# Umbraco 7 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, umbraco7

Ive got Umbraco 7 installed on my web server with the usual default skins and such and, what I want to do is create my own template(s) to use on the site ill be creating.  Now Ive looked at all the documentation in Umbraco and all it really spends its time doing is talking about using an existing template code then adding CSS, Javascript and such.  that's all well and good, but I want to use visual studio to develop this site/Application.  the problem is that the Visual Studio template developed by Warren Buckley doesn't work on Visual Studio 2013 at all and there's no sign of him sorting this out it would seem...

What I want to do is develop the various templates I need, then add Bootstrap, develop custom menus, Forms for Credit card processing, emailing, etc (Not sure where you do this in Umbraco.. Macros perhaps?) then manage the content only in Umbraco.  The developers of Umbraco don't seem to grasp the existence of Visual Studio or updating any documentation concerning Visual studio 2013 or Umbraco 7.

In short, All I bloody want to do is develop this Friggin thing in VS 2013, then manage content in Umbraco..  Umbraco is installed and running, VS 2013 sees the file content and can communicate with the web server perfectly..

Any help on this would be hot!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using NuGet. Just create an empty project in Visual Studio, go to Nuget Package Manager Console and type

Install-Package UmbracoCms

Then it installs everything you need, and once it's done you run the application and it jumps straight into the setup. You can choose a custom setup where you choose DB options and starter kits and so forth.

And it definitely works in Visual Studio, I've done it plenty of times.

Comment: Done that and am very familiar with the NuGET, it is a very handy and powerful tool to use but, how do you get going with developing views and coding in visual studio?  This is the root of the problem. How do you develop .cshtml pages as normally when developing an application,  I would create the class first, then let MVC build the view for me.  This is not the case in Umbraco as from what I've established, you code the page in ASP.net, then use RAZOR to confirm to Umbraco's Model, then Umbraco does the rest.  Then you create pages and content within the back-office and im fine with this.

Comment: Okay, well, if you installed the starter kit you should be able to see how it's done then? The MVC stuff in Umbraco is confusing to me as well, but in the Umbraco backend (in the Developer section) you can have Umbraco create template files, style sheets, partial views and such. Those files can then easily be added to the VS solution, from where you can work with them.

Comment: Have you seen this "tutorial"? https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Creating-Basic-Site/

Comment: I agree its helped alot looking at the file structure and the model in its raw state within VS2013.  So, Moving forward on this, If I approach this as manipulate an existing template page, then add my own HTML, CSS, Jscript, ETC and place them in their appropriate folders, link them on the template, Umbraco will automatically pick these up in the back-office upon refresh/reload? And I totally agree with you on the MVC approach that Umbraco takes..  Unconventional to say the least!!!

Comment: Well, all files that Umbraco doesn't use directly (like CSS or JS files) can be created freely in Visual Studio and referenced from your template. Some of them will even be recognized by Umbraco on the spot. No problem.Partial Views, macro partials, new template files and such is much easier to create via Umbraco backend.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd recommend buying one month of Umbraco TV and watching the Implementor and Developer track: http://umbraco.tv/

Generally, you can edit css, js, views, and partial views in Visual Studio.  You will need to create Document Types in the back-office because they are in the database.  That is, unless you want to use a code-first style package like Ditto: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/ditto.

Also, the Templates actually have a record in the database.  So you must create them in the back-office if you need to connect them to DocumentTypes / Content.  Or you could use code-first.

Comment: I totally agree with you on the Umbraco.TV subscription. Will be taking this on next month.

On the second paragraph, I get you on that and looking into Ditto.  I take it that Ditto automatically binds itself to the editor so you can code in a more "Code first" fashion?

So ill need to create the templates in the back-office as well but could use Ditto.  

Also, if you create a template, using the back office, then edit it in visual studio, will it update in the back office and the view?  Ta

Comment: For Ditto and some of the other CodeFirst packages you would create classes / models and decorate them with attributes that tell Umbraco what editors, types, names, etc to load into the database.  The packages usually run on startup or have some sort of loading process to pull in changes.